# MS Word delimiter

Tags: python, ms-word, character

I just wanted to format some output so that I can easily copy it to clipboard and into a preformatted Microsoft Word Document (a table).

The characters I've figured are `\t` as seperation character from data cell to data cell, and `\n` for a new data row. What I have trouble is when I want a newline inside of a cell.

I've copied the content of a table cell into an editor and did a hexdump which resulted in `0a20` (new line feed and data link espace). I tried to output my data with those characters at the end of where I wanted a line, but when I copy that into word, it always jumps into the next table row.

Any ideas which character it might be? Or is it a problem of outputting it to a file and copying it from there?

Comment: Does word support importing CSV data? If so, [the `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) could probably do it for you and save a ton of extra effort.

Comment: It's not that much data. Enough to want a tool to do it for you, too little to have it in some file format that needs to be imported. It'd be really cool, if I could just copy and paste it into the table, correctly formated already.

Comment: Is doing an import really that much more work than a copy/paste?

Comment: @bibadiak - I get `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0d0a' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)` when I try to add that character.

Comment: @Lattyware It seems like it can't easily read CSV

Comment: Is it possible that things get lost when I copy from my VM (Linux) to my host (Windows)?